# How do you get the Facebook apiKey from the Javascript API?

Tags: facebook, api

It used to be the case that you could test for the presence of a valid api key in the Javascript API by checking `FB._apiKey`.  However, it looks like that has gone away in the latest deprecations to the API (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/16/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/):

> In the upcoming weeks, we will be updating the Javascript SDK to limit the publicly exposed interface. This is part of an ongoing process to improve the reliability of the SDK. The first step will include removing access to all internal properties and to methods prefixed with _.

So: Is there another way to get at what was previously available via `FB._apiKey`?

Comment: No idea, but I'm curious as for what you need it for?

Comment: I'm working with some people (well, using what they do, really :) on a Drupal package for Facebook.  A previous version of the code used FB._apiKey as a test for the status of the FB connection.  I think.  In any case, an alternative solution seems to be underway.

Answer (score 1):

You typically initialize FB.init with your appId (aka API Key)

You can always store that as a separate variable and reference it, like so:

```
window.fbKey = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : fbKey, // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
```